# Изображения Wordpress

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Каким образом можно изменять изображения при загрузке на CMS Wordpress?

Т.е., к примеру, я хочу применить к изображению функцию imagerotate, какими способами можно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте плагины для этого. Возможно [NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) не плохой.

Answer (score 0):

Есть класс `timthumb`, выводимый изображения ты можешь прогонять через него, там можно также поворачивать изображение. Работает быстро, практически не заметишь разницы.